# Purpose of work council representative attending an interview?

Tags: interviewing, germany, unions

I will attend a technical interview in the near future for a position at a German company. In addition to technical managers, the interview board will include a representative of the local work council (as I was told). However, I am not accustomed to German work laws (I am not German) so I do not know about the purpose of this representative. Is he/she related to HR? Do I have to expect specific questions from him/her?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: They are probably seeing if you know how to comply to local laws etc... Treat it as a normal interview but be prepared to answer questions on local customs

Comment: If I understand this right, this is the Betriebsrat, which is a kind of in-company union representative. Most likely he is there to check that the employer doesn't break any regulations.

Comment: Is this for a permanent position, or contract?

Comment: @Mawg Permanent

Answer (score 3):

Wilbert's answer is probably right. Afaik the Betriebsrat can only sit in with the employer's permission and their purpose is to make sure that the employer adheres to the rules (no questions about family status, religion, ...) and that you're not discriminated against based on forbidden categories.
They are only allowed to observe, so you don't need to prepare for questions from them.

That said, I'm not a member of a Betriebsrat so i haven't had the training that explains these rules. Betriebsrat-members feel free to write a better answer and I'll delete mine.